# How do I make custom bootsplash and wallpapers

Tags: plymouth, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I would like to customize my Ubuntu install with my own Wallpaper.

I know where to change the wallpapers

I copy my wallpaper in `/usr/share/wallpapers` and then modify the contests/xml file in order to use it but thats about it.

how can I also change the following with the same Image:

- the login image(lightdm)
- boot screen and shutdown screen(plymouth)

Comment: i dont want to customize a live cd, i want to customize the images only

Comment: Ah, in that case, you are asking multiple questions here. The site works best if you split them up. :)

Comment: @jrg i have to ask 4 different questions. 1 = login, 2 = boot, 3 = shutdown and 4 for other cases?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Edit /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf and change "background" value:

```
background=/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

or you can try this: [@Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/simple-lightdm-manager-change-lightdm.html)

2 - You can try Zorin Splash Screen Manager: [@Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/install-and-change-plymouth-themes-in.html), making a copy of the current theme (located at /lib/plymouth/themes/), changing it at your needs and installing it.

3 - I think the theme used to boot is the same used in shutdown...

Comment: i get: root@laptop:~# ll /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
**ls: cannot access /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf: No such file or directory** webupd8 seem very nice thanks